# Android File Transfer app is not optimized for your mac latest version

Tags: android, file, transfer, usb-debugging

I get an "Android File Transfer app is not optimized for your mac latest version.." warning even if I have updated the app to latest version (1.0.12)

Have checked the app via "System Report -> Applications" and it says: 64 bit.

I would not install the new Catalina before I know that Android File Transfer works. 
Or are there any alternatives that can be used for USB debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I found other alternatives that make file transfer possible. USB debugging works without it so this issue is closed

Comment: What are these alternatives?